# $injector:strictdi - Angular Provider

Tags: angularjs, provider

I have an error in my code :

```
angular.js:38 Uncaught Error: [$injector:strictdi] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/strictdi?p0=%24exceptionHandler
```

I know this from a code style issue, but I can not find the syntax for it respects the **"strictDi : true"**

For information, when I do not use the parameter **"strictDi : true ,"** my app works well.

Do you have an idea.

Thanks for your help.

```
cnaflog.provider(
    "$exceptionHandler",
    {
        $get: function( errorLogService ) {
            return( errorLogService );
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use minification-safe dependency injection with array notation:

```
cnaflog.provider(
    "$exceptionHandler",
    {
        $get: ['errorLogService', function( errorLogService ) {
            return( errorLogService );
        }]
    }
);
```